# Automate finding linux lib dependencies for python packages

Tags: python, pip, yum, apt

I thinking about some problem for my pet project:
How can i get linux dependency for any python package before install?
For example we can get python packages dependency list by using pip deptree

in `https://pypi.org/pypi/\<package\>/\<version\>/json`
i dont see info about linux packages needed for package
for example in package pytorch we need glibs how to know this before install
and so i dont understand how to prevent errors and automate finding linux libs dependencies for pip packages

Try to automate finding linux dependecies for python packages

Comment: No way. Python packages are intended to be installed on BSD, Linux, MacOS, Windows, whatever; they don't declare Linux dependencies, even less distributive-specific dependencies. Only packages converted to proper distributive-specific formats (RPM, DEB) declare specific dependencies.

Comment: thx u its good idea) we can try find RPM reference for pip package)))) for example https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/PyYAML-3.10-11.el7.x86_64.rpm.html we can see list of requrements libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) -
libpthread.so.0()(64bit) -
libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit) -
libyaml-0.so.2()(64bit) -
python(abi) = 2.7
rtld(GNU_HASH) -